# Get data outside Loop in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an issue where it returns an `unidentified` when I tried to console the data by clicking get all input type data, All I want is to get the value of each input type and store it on list using `push` should I make another for loop? just to reiterate each value?

```
var selected_obj ={ 
            quantity: testtttttt examplee
       }
selected_items.push(selected_obj);
```

[image]

**what I've tried**

```js
$("#allcb").change(function() {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div class="row" data-for="' + checkBoxes[i].id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
        checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
      }
    }
    $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });


  $("#get_data").click(function() {
    var selected_items = [];
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');

    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
      console.log(value_input);
      console.log("test");

      var selected_obj ={ 
            quantity: value_input
       }
      selected_items.push(selected_obj);
    }


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1" id="Table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
          </th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
          </td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td> 25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
          </td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
          </td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="add_data">Add datas</button>
    <button type="button" id="get_data">Get all input type data</button>
    
    <ul class="list-group mb-3 row whole-div-class"></ul>
```

Comment: `testtttttt examplee` is an invalid string

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza first thing, why you have open the get all input button when there is no item in added. ??? What do you want to acheive here>

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza and why are you looping over checkboxes in get all input method.?? It should only get all input fields values and sum up and show them on console. Right?? Is this you want?

Comment: @Developer First thing I want to get the value of all checkboxes after it added to the list, after it added to the list, it will easily to get all data through list and past it to my backend, I've been using Django but I'm I trying to get all value of checkbox but it says Unidentified

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan it just a sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the input elements by class, then use `map` to get an array of objects.

```js
const selectedItems = $('.quantity_input').map((i, el) => ({quantity: el.value})).get();
```

Comment: I think it works one last thing can I get also  the `checkBoxes[i].id` through this? it just like `const selectedItems = $('.quantity_input').map((i, el) => ({stockid: checkBoxes[i].id ,quantity: el.value})).get();`

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza Yes, you could have `const checkBoxes = $('input[type=checkbox]')`, then your code should work.